# Cut elements from html string (PHP)

Tags: php, string, extract

Let's say I have this HTML as a string -

```
<div>
lorem ipsum
<p>dolor</p>
</div>

<hr>

<ul>
<li>value</li>
<li>value</li>
</ul>

<a>read more</a>
<a>read more</a>
```

I want to split the HTML and take only what's after the HR element.

Then I want to split the code left into list, and two links.

Eventually I want to get something like -

```
$list = "<ul><li>value</li><li>value</li></ul>"

$link1 = "<a>read more</a>"

$link2 = "<a>read more</a>"
```

Could anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Do you want to get all tags or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $str = "<div>
            lorem ipsum
            <p>dolor</p>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <ul>
            <li>value</li>
            <li>value</li>
            </ul>

            <a>read more</a>
            <a>read more</a>";

            $str = htmlentities($str);
            $str = explode("&lt;hr&gt;", $str);
            echo $str[1]; //ul+a



           $str2 = explode("&lt;/ul&gt;", $str[1]);
           echo $str2[1]; //a
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was hoping for :)

Comment: Any idea on how to split the two links?

Comment: Updated But better use some html php html parser like "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser"

Comment: Actually I meant the each link has its own variable. But thank you!!

Comment: You will have better controlled with "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser"

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$string = '<div>
lorem ipsum
<p>dolor</p>
</div>

<hr>

<ul>
<li>value</li>
<li>value</li>
</ul>

<a>read more</a>
<a>read more</a>';

$cut = explode("<hr>", $string);
echo $cut[1];
```